# Visual Basic Parsing Nested JSON file

Tags: arrays, json, excel, vba

So I have this nested JSON file

```
{

   "root": [{

       "STATUS_RE": {

            "STATUS": {

              "STATUS": {

                          "OWNER": "Manny",
                          "REQUEST_ID": "00000",
                          "STATE": "SUCCESS"

                         }

                     },

                    "RESPONSE_FORMAT": "New",

                    "OWNER": "Manny",

                    "REQUEST_ID": "00000",

                    "RESULT": [{

                        "USER": {

                              "BUSINESS_ID": "N",

                              "ID_NUMBER": "016",

                              "U_LANGUAGE": "F",

                              "B_CODE": "08302"

                        }

                    },

                 {

                   "USER_A": {

                         ROLE": "true",

                         "ACCESSING": "true"
                         }
                   }
                  }
                }]
              }
```

Im using this visual basic code trying to access certain part of this json file. For example I want "BUSINESS_ID" and "ID_Number" under "USER" and I also want "ROLE" under "USER_A"

This is the code I'm working with

```
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim JsonTS As TextStream
Set JsonTS = FSO.OpenTextFile("example.json", ForReading)
JsonText = JsonTS.ReadAll
JsonTS.Close
Set JSON = ParseJson(JsonText)
i = 2
For Each Item In JSON
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = Item("BUSINESS_ID")
Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value = Item("ID_Number")
i = i + 1
```

I tried changing `For Each Item In JSON` to something like `For Each Item In JSON("root")(STATUS_RE")....` all the way to `("USER")` then grab the "BUSINESS_ID" but that did not work, how would I extract the information I need.

Comment: Helps to show exactly how you're parsing your JSON...  Also helps to post a complete JSON sample

Comment: I edited my VBA code and im using the JsonConverter.bas library

Comment: Can you post a valid, parseable sample of your JSON?

Comment: there not much else, I just didnt close it

Comment: So I should do it?  People here (including me) typically like to test the solutions they post, so don't make it difficult...

Comment: Sorry didnt know that, added the closing

Comment: Where's the closing `]`?  And your "USER" object is invalid (extra comma)

Comment: should be fixed

Comment: not fixed. Can't you just *post your actual JSON* and edit any "sensitive" values?

Comment: @KevinJones Is this now answered? It looks to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
Dim result As String
Dim JSON As Object

result = Range("A9").Value

Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(result)
Debug.Print JSON("root")(1)("STATUS_RE")("RESULT")(1)("USER")("ID_NUMBER") '>> 016
```